# MongDB sometimes not returning results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

This is very strange, but here goes.

I am using the sailsjs framework and a mongodb backend. Occasionally I get an error that the framework is unable to find a record that I know for a fact exists in the DB. I have enable logging in mongo `db.setLogLevel(1)` and the output is as follow. The same query does not get data then it does and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

No data returned, no docsExamined

```
2020-05-05T15:51:16.220+0200 I COMMAND  [conn82] command sails.services command: find { find: "services", filter: { userId: "5de7808067988c7f1e580895" }, projection: {}, limit: 1, $db: "sails" } planSummary: IXSCAN { userId: 1 } keysExamined:0 docsExamined:0 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:0 reslen:102 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms
```

Data returned as expected

```
2020-05-05T16:02:03.781+0200 I COMMAND  [conn68] command sails.services command: find { find: "services", filter: { userId: "5de7808067988c7f1e580895" }, projection: {}, limit: 1, $db: "sails" } planSummary: IXSCAN { userId: 1 } keysExamined:1 docsExamined:1 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:0 nreturned:1 reslen:318 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 2 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 1 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 1 } } } protocol:op_query 0ms
```

userId is indexed on the services Collection

```
> db.services.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "sails.services"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "username" : 1
        },
        "name" : "username_1",
        "ns" : "sails.services"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "userId" : 1
        },
        "name" : "userId_1",
        "ns" : "sails.services"
    }
]
```

As the queries are returning nothing from the mongod.log, I assume this has nothing to do with sails. Does anyone have any hint as to why/how this can happen and, maybe, how I can fix this?

`MongoDB server version: 3.6.9`

`Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

EDIT:

As the query comes from sails.js, my query is as follows.

```
  usage: function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.param('userId')


            Services.findOne({ userId: userId}).exec(function (err, service) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Clients/Usage -2 ####Error finding service with userId: ' + userId, err)
                return res.send(401, err)
              } else {
                if (service === undefined) {
                  console.log('Clients/Usage -2 ####No service found')
                  return res.send(401, 'No service found')
                } else {
                  console.log('Clients/Usage -2 DEBUG! sending service as a response', service)
                  return res.send(201, service)
                }
              }
            })
}
```

users hit the api at `services/usage?id=`

Comment: Explain to me again what test command you invoked, and what your expected result was and what your actual result was.

Comment: @Wyck I have edited my post to explain how the query is built

Comment: Can you tell us anything more about the flakiness of "sometimes"?  When you say _MongDB *sometimes* not returning results_

Comment: @Wyck yes. So if you have a look at the initial post, the excerpt from the mongod.log you can see that the same query `find { find: "services", filter: { userId: "5de7808067988c7f1e580895" }, projection: {}, limit: 1, $db: "sails" }` 

returned 0 results at 2020-05-05T15:51:16.220+0200
returned 1 result at 2020-05-05T16:02:03.781+0200

meanwhile this record was created in `createdAt: "2020-05-05T13:51:17.368Z"`

Comment: What about modified?  It's conceivable that the query might miss the document if it's being modified while the query is running.  See https://blog.meteor.com/mongodb-queries-dont-always-return-all-matching-documents-654b6594a827

Comment: @Wyck I saw that post, because of that I dropped the index as "This issue doesn’t affect queries that don’t use an index, such as queries that just look up a document by ID". I also do not think this the case as the document has not been updated since creation `updatedAt: "2020-05-05T13:51:17.368Z",`